# MYSQL select using concat with not in statment

Tags: mysql

can someone correct me on this syntax error. am trying to search users by firstname, lastname and their email

```
SELECT
  USERID,
  FNAME,
  LNAME
FROM
  USERS
WHERE
  CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword ', ' ', '%'), '%', '%') NOT IN (
    SELECT
      PRODUCT_ID
    FROM
      ITEMS
    WHERE
      USER = 'JANE'
      AND PRICE = '400'
      AND ORDER = 'PAID'
  )
```

i want to search and get userid,firstname and lastname. but i dont want to get jane, price = 400 and order = paid

```
TABLE USER

USERID        FNAME     LNAME          EMAIL 
1             JANE      DEO          TES@TED.COM
2              KEL      DEO          TES@TED.COM
3              MK       DEO          TES@TED.COM


TABLE ITEMS 

PRODUCT_ID  PRICE    ITEM_NUM  USER    USERID
1           400        40      JANE       1
2           200        20      KEL        2
3           100        10      MK         3
```

so i want to get the rest people apart from JANE ROW

AND MY TRY IS

```
SELECT SND.USERID, SND.FNAME, SND.LNAME WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%') FROM items as M JOIN users as SND ON SND.USERID WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE M.USER = 'JANE' AND M.PRICE ='400' AND M.ITEM_NUM ='40')
```

Comment: How are you exactly trying to link between USERS table and ITEMS table ? In USERS table you have user related data. In ITEMS table, you have Items related data. Where is the relation between USERS and ITEMS ? Is there any other table in the middle ?

Comment: thanks @PraveenE for your response. its like i want to select from tble users  but check in to tble items if some info exits.    and this was working for me just selecting single tble  `SELECT USERID, FNAME, LNAME FROM USERS WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(?, ' ', '%'), '%', '%')"`        i will appreciate if you can show me how to join them. an example

Comment: this is my try `SELECT
  SND.USERID, SND.FNAME, SND.LNAME WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%')  FROM
  items as M
  JOIN users as SND ON SND.USERID = M.PRODUCT_ID WHERE M.USER = 'JANE' AND M.PRICE ='400' AND M.ITEM_NUM ='40'`

Comment: What from the `USERS` tables are you trying to ensure isn't in the `ITEMS` table? What field in the `ITEMS` does this match too?

Comment: @danblack i have made some edit you can see it clear now

Comment: i have made a try and clear example of wat i done. but just not correction. coz there still syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include a where clause between the select and the from clauses

```
SELECT
   SND.USERID
 , SND.FNAME
 , SND.LNAME

>> no where clause here

FROM items AS M
INNER JOIN users AS SND ON SND.USERID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ITEMS
  WHERE M.USER = 'JANE'
   AND M.PRICE = '400'
   AND M.ITEM_NUM = '40'
  )
```

Just include all the wanted conditions int the one (and only) where clause, combine those using AND's or OR's as needed. I have changed the join condition, and altered the NOT syntax used also.

```
SELECT
   SND.USERID
 , SND.FNAME
 , SND.LNAME
FROM items AS M
INNER JOIN users AS SND ON M.userid = SND.userid
WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%') 
AND NOT (
       M.USER = 'JANE'
   AND M.PRICE = '400'
   AND M.ITEM_NUM = '40'
  )
```

I'm not that comfortable with your use of `concat()` in the above however, it looks very inefficient, instead why not just repeat the LIKE tests on each column. (Yes it may make the SQL code longer, but that is not an indicator of the execution time of the query.)

```
SELECT
   SND.USERID
 , SND.FNAME
 , SND.LNAME
FROM items AS M
INNER JOIN users AS SND ON M.userid = SND.userid
WHERE (
   SND.FNAME LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'))
or SND.LNAME LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'))
or SND.EMAIL LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'))
)
AND NOT (
       M.USER = 'JANE'
   AND M.PRICE = '400'
   AND M.ITEM_NUM = '40'
  )
```

Note the use of indents and parentheses when using or in a where clause. (You do not have to place SQL into one row, not sure why you did that in the question.)

Comment: thanks i tried your example and works. but it was only selecting from items where by i wanted it to select from users and join items to find wat rows we dont want to ouput. here is my code now. `SELECT
  SND.USERID,
  SND.FNAME,
  SND.LNAME
FROM users AS SND
INNER JOIN items AS M
WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('keyword', ' ', '%'), '%', '%')");` but the problem i get each results repeated 4 times

Comment: ya i made some changes may be added if you want it to be there as decoration.. how can i solve this. coz i removed AND NOT. fix it step by step. but i still get results repeated 4 times. but good thing i get resluts. but only the problem being repeat results 4 times

Comment: Without access to data all i can suggest you use `select distinct`

Comment: u got magic in your head. lol i had almost 10 lines of sql code disturbing me to figure out. lol but DISTINCT fixed the problem. thanks much man